# Vaadin Grid numbering of the rows

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm new to the vaadin. And I had a question how to create the numbering of lines in the grid using `grid.addColumn(???).setHeader("#")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easiest to do with TemplateRenderer this way

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.of("[[index]]")).setHeader("#")
```

So then you would get index of the row in the column (which will not depend on Bean content, sorting etc.) There is more info about TempateRenderer in [Vaadin Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html)

Comment: Сan this example be redone so that the numbering starts not from 0 but from 1? Or should I look for another component for this?